# Define function twice in JS. Indicate which definition to use depending on web page

Tags: javascript

I have two web pages. They share the same .js file, but the file contains code that I only want to execute for one or the other of the pages.

I thought I could handle it like below, where each page has an element with a unique id, either "page_1" or "page_2". The js then tests for the existence of this element before executing the code.

However, on page_1, even though it doesn't actually execute the code inside the page_2 IF statement, the function runStartFunction() is still overridden because it is defined twice.

How can I avoid this? Obviously I could give all the functions different names, but I have a lot of pages and I could accidentally use the same name at some point.

```
if (document.getElementById("page_1") != null){
    alert("Page 1"); // executed, as expected
    function runStartFunction(){
        alert("what I want"); // not executed, but should be
    }
}

 if (document.getElementById("page_2") != null){
   alert("Page 2"); // not executed, as expected
   function runStartFunction(){ 
        alert("what I don't want"); // executed, but shouldn't be
   }
 }

runStartFunction();
```

Comment: mixing up the js code for two different webpages? i don't think that's a very good idea.

Comment: It's very common. They are pages within the same site and it cuts down on the number of calls to load scipts.

Comment: Let your backend code decide which js files will get loaded based on which view it renders, this will reduce your overall JS that need's to get loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i stated in my comment, i don't think this is a good idea, but still i'll provide you with a way to solve your problem: Use [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

```
var runStartFunction;
if (document.getElementById("page_1") != null){
    (function () { 
        alert("Page 1"); // executed, as expected
        runStartFunction = function startFunction(){
            alert("what I want"); // not executed, but should be
        }
    }());
}

if (document.getElementById("page_2") != null){
    (function () { 
        alert("Page 2"); // not executed, as expected
        runStartFunction = function startFunction(){ 
            alert("what I don't want"); // executed, but shouldn't be
        }
    }());
}

runStartFunction();
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I also added an answer based on yours, which shows how I actually ended up doing it.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, function declaration is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#function). Your code becomes:

```
function runStartFunction() {
    alert("what I want");
}

function runStartFunction() { 
    alert("what I don't want");
}

if (document.getElementById("page_1") != null) {
    alert("Page 1");
}

if (document.getElementById("page_2") != null) {
    alert("Page 2");
}

runStartFunction();
```

The second declaration of `runStartFunction` overrides the first one, so second one called.

You can use function expression and assignment instead of declaration to solve this problem like this:

```
var runStartFunction;

if (document.getElementById("page_1") != null) {
    alert("Page 1");
    runStartFunction = function () {
        alert("what I want");
    };
}

if (document.getElementById("page_2") != null) {
    alert("Page 2");
    runStartFunction = function () { 
        alert("what I don't want");
    };
}

runStartFunction();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nYPME

Answer (score 0):

Based on Manuel Görlich's answer, here is how I ended up doing it. I surround each code set in a closure and then I just leave everything else as it was. The call to runStartFunction() has to be inside each closure.

```
if (document.getElementById("page_1") != null){(function () { 

   alert("Page 1");
   function runStartFunction(){
        alert("what I want");
    }
    runStartFunction();

}());}

if (document.getElementById("page_2") != null){(function () { 


    alert("Page 2");
    function runStartFunction(){ 
        alert("what I don't want");
     }
    runStartFunction(); 

}());}
```